# V8 engine. Как создать callback (без Node JS)?

Tags: c++, v8

Пытался я создать callback в v8 js engine но что то не получается.
То есть у меня не получается сохранить функцию чтобы потом ее вызвать.
Перешерстил пол гугла но там все написано о том как это сделать через Node JS.
А можно обойтись без него ?
PS:
Под callback'ом я имею введу вот это:

```
function Func()
{
    print("YEEES");
}
cl.register(Func);
```

Пытался сохранять вот так:

```
v8::Persistent<v8::Function> *savedFunc = NULL;
Locker locker(_isolate);
HandleScope scope(_isolate);
Handle<Function> args1 = Handle<Function>::Cast(args[0]);

savedFunc = new v8::Persistent<v8::Function>();
savedFunc->Reset(_isolate, args1);
```

Мне это нужно чтобы описать действия программы на JS.
То есть к примеру добавить событие нажатия кнопки или движения мышкой и вызвать его из C++.(это если что для игры делаю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому то надо будет это...
Файл с кодом на github: [v8/samples/process.cc](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/ffee558e14e28fc8b1f9a3c10ea3615e0d686c7b/samples/process.cc)
Тут вызов метода Process легко переделать в callback.
Только чего там нет так это самой регистрации каллбека.
Вот как получилось ее реализовать:

```
if (args.Length() < 1) return;
Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
HandleScope scope(isolate);
Local<Value> arg = args[0];
if (!arg->IsFunction()) {
    return;
}
Local<Function> process_fun = Local<Function>::Cast(arg);
process_f.Reset(isolate, process_fun);
```

Код на JS

```
function proc()
{
    log("Print: " + a);
    a++;
}
callback(proc);
```

[Готовый код | Warning: Там много ненужного мусора так как делал для теста](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212143/how-create-async-callback-function-in-v8-c-not-using-node-js)

Comment: Ну ок... Удалил.

Comment: Так ссылку оставлять или весь код из того файла ?

Comment: @VladD ойййййй прошу прощения... Я из VS это копировал и не заметил.
Просто для теста написал какую то фигню чтобы видно было или работает

Comment: Ничего страшного :) На вашу ссылку набросилась эвристика движка сайта и посчитала её спамом, вот я и поменял текст.

Comment: @VladD, ответ выше это про "pityx".
А ссылка наверное считается спамом потому что там есть вот это: ffee558e14e28fc8b1f9a3c10ea3615e0d686c7b

Comment: Как я понимаю, эвристика посчитала process.cc адресом сайта. То есть она увидела, что в тексте один адрес, а в ссылке другой, и возмутилась.

Comment: @VladD ух какая плохая))